# How to write alerts from field in one line?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am checking the input from the text area with regex, and if there is an error it gives an alert

this is my script:

```
var lines = dateinput.value.split(/\r?\n/);
for(var i = 0; i<lines.length ; i++){
    if (lines[i].match(regex) == null) {
        alert('There is an error in the ' + (i + 1) + ' line. Please enter a valid date formatted DD/MM/YYYY');
    }
}
```

It can be annoying if you have a lot of them

is there a way to write all the wrong lines into one alert?

Comment: append all the errors as a string in a variable and alert it after your last check (after the `for` loop)

Comment: ...or add the invalid line numbers to an array, and form an alert if the array contains any elements, which is faster!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rough but something like this will work.

```
var lines = dateinput.value.split(/\r?\n/);
var wrongLines ="";
for(var i = 0; i<lines.length ; i++){
    if (lines[i].match(regex) == null) {
        wrongLines += i + 1 +",";
    }
}
if(wrongLines != "")
 alert('There is an error in the ' + wrongLines + ' line(s). Please enter a valid date formatted DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate all errors to a single message (i.e. a string variable) and alert it after the `for` loop is run:

```
var lines = dateinput.value.split(/\r?\n/);
var message = '';
for(var i = 0; i<lines.length ; i++){
    if (lines[i].match(regex) == null) {
        message += 'There is an error in the ' + (i + 1) +
        ' line. Please enter a valid date formatted DD/MM/YYYY' + '\n';
    }
}
if(message != '')
    alert(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. (And this is a better answer because 1. It doesn't write the error message many times, and 2. It is faster, as join on an array works better than concatenating strings with `+=`)

```
var errors = [];
var lines = dateinput.value.split(/\r?\n/);
for(var i = 0; i<lines.length ; i++){
    if (lines[i].match(regex) == null) {
        errors.push(i + 1)
    }
}
if(errors.length > 0){
    alert('There is an error in the line(s) ' + errors.join(", ") + ' Please enter valid dates formatted DD/MM/YYYY');
}
```

this collects the invalid line numbers in an array, and simply calls the alert, if any lines failed the test.